# Redirect css|js|img|fonts folder using .htaccess

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I'm on shared hosting where some website live.

I have to move a ZendFramework2 on this server by adding it in a directory from the root (dir name = site).  Controllers and actions are working right but I can't load any css, images or javascript.

Here are my directories :

```
/root/website1 (example.com/website1)
/root/website2 (example.com/website2)
/root/site     (example.com/site)
/root/site/application
/root/site/data
/root/site/library
/root/site/public
/root/site/public/css
/root/site/public/fonts
/root/site/public/img
/root/site/public/js
/root/site/public/.htaccess
/root/site/.htaccess
```

.htacces in /site folder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^site/public/.*$ /site/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

.htacces in /site/public folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/index.php [NC,L]
```

css tag :

```
<link href="/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Can i redirect /css/global.css to load /site/public/css/global.css ?

Sure, i could change for ...

```
<link href="/site/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

... but i prefer not to change href

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. What is the public directory if you call your Website http://example.com/ is it /root or /root/site or /root/site/public

Comment: The public directory is for protection only. Everything the user must see is there (images, scripts, css, fonts). Everything that is not in public is the server-side code and configs which are protected by directory levels.

Comment: Yes I know this, but that dose not answer my question, if /root/site/public would be your real public folder than example.com/css/global.css would show the CSS, but because this is not the case, what is your root directory? is it /root or /root/site

Comment: /root is in fact apache htdocs where are located every web site directory. So, there is nothing in /root/. The document root of site has to be /root/site and example.com/site/css/global.css is what i'm looking for

Comment: For the moment I'm only interested how your Hoster has configured your webspace. If you would delete all files from your webspace and call your website in the browser, what would be the Document Root? Would you get the content of /root or /root/site. Because your first .htaccess file is in /root/site, I assume your Document Root it /root/site and not /root. If this is the case than we don't have to take care about the /site folder only about /public. If not I wondering how it workers that you will be redirected to your index.php file in the public folder if you have no .htaccess file in /root.

Comment: the first .htacces is a tweak to make ZF2 works on virtual shared hosting as you can see  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193101/zend-how-to-make-it-works-on-a-shared-host/26205597#26205597">here</a>. So the website has to move on a shared hosting where other website runs

example.com/foo/
example.com/bar
example.com/site

Before, the website was directly in example.com/ with no sub directory. So this where things get harder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155540/discussion-between-webdesigner-and-bigpino).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create only one .htaccess file to solve all your problems.  Please put this into your /root folder and delete the other .htaccess files.

```
# This first part should be done by the webserver,
# if not than thing about to change you hoster but I put it here:
# Preventing direct access to any .ht file (.htaccess, .htpasswd, etc.)
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

# Start to Rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# For all URL starting with /css, /fonts, /img or /js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(css|fonts|img|js)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/public/%1%2 [L]

# Redirect all to the Application if not done already
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?site/public/index\.php [NC]
# but not if the URL starts with css, fonts, img or js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|fonts|img|js)(/.*)?$ [NC]
# or if request is a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# or if request is a real directory but not the root directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite the rest to the index.php file in your public folder
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That makes the job !!! Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciates it